# How to enter text to the cursor's position using C programming?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a program that takes the user's two input cursor positions, for where the program needs to type in some information, however I am having issues finding a way to have the program enter the automated text, as the outputs I know about are all console based. Any help?
I am fairly new to C programming.

Comment: You need to supply some details about your environment is this at the console of in a GUI. C does not have any inherent GUI support so the answer depends entirely on your environment

Comment: Show your current progress.

Comment: What kind of input is it?  Is it a text box on a windows form or is it something else?

Comment: each platform has a different way to send inputs to other programs